# How to create c# class for json object?

Tags: c#, json

Below one is my json object

```
{
   "LNK" : "862",
   "MUK" : "861",
   "query" : "java"
}
```

I want to capture LNK and the corresponding handle. I've tried:

```
var result = Deserializejson<Dictionary<string,Search>>(jsonresponse);
var searchhandles = new List<Search>(result.Count);
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: var result = Deserializejson<Dictionary<string,Search>>(jsonresponse);
            var searchhandles = new List<Search>(result.Count);

Comment: { "be": "Belgium", "fr": "France", "uk": "Great-Britain", "nl": "Nederland" } . I want to capture the above key value pair in c# List

Answer (score 1):

if using [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)  and Deserilize the JSON into object

```
   dynamic obj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

create a Model class to map to your Json Sructure or use dynmamics

:EDIT: sorry syntax was wrong, here we have a full example

```
        var seri = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();

        dynamic dynamicObject = new
        {
            LNK = "862",
            MUK = "861",
            query = "java"
        };

        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var writer = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter);
            seri.Serialize(writer, dynamicObject);

            var result = textWriter.ToString();
        }
```

works, too:

```
        dynamic dynamicObject = new
        {
            LNK = "862",
            MUK = "861",
            query = "java"
        };

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynamicObject);
```

For serialization/deserialization there are different libraries. Apart from the .Net standard I highly recommend the Json.Net library which is available via Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

It is just another option you may try. You can use `JSONObject` in case the JSON you have in hand is not of a predefined structure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject(v=vs.95).aspx